# creating artifical neutral point in delta connection

Tags: microcontroller, power, energy, y-to-delta

I am trying to measure 3 phase 3wire and 3 phase 4 wire  L_L voltage and L_N voltage.Circuit i am looking is common for both. 
In star connection i will get an neutral point for reference to read the accurate reading
in delta connection i wont have neutral reference but i wanted to create virtual neutral point. can someone suggest me circuit that can interface to MCU with above requirement

1. How to create virtual neutral point for delta connection
2. how can i differentiate real and virtual neutral point
3. is it safe when actual neutral point connected to virtual neutral point.
4. i have seen some application using this kind of circuit,I could not able get operation / functionality.mainly used for star and delta connection.
5. Is there any other technique where i could use Y and delta connection as common
   [78m6631](https://datasheets.maximintegrated.com/en/ds/78M6631.pdf)
   [MCP3914](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/MCP3914-Data-Sheet-DS20005216B.pdf)
   [ADE7880](https://www.analog.com/en/products/ade7880.html#product-evaluationkit)

but i have used this IC there is no issue while reading star connection. but when connected in delta it make huge difference.

[image: List item]

Comment: The reason for virtual or a high-impedance neutral is to keep the phases in a delta configuration from floating with no reference to Earth ground. If the 3 phases have the same voltage, the floating neutral is close to zero volts. Capacitors have to be X2 rated.

Comment: @Sparky256 do you have any recommend circuit that can interface with MCU . with sefety grounding